# How to handle too many database connection in PHP without an increase to max connections?

Tags: php, mysql

There is a file called `function.php` and I am calling it into all my website's pages with `require_once`. This file contains more than hundred functions.

I get `max_user_connections` error from `mysqli_connect()` and right after that

```
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given
```

error shown when there are too many visitors or search engine bots are crawling fast.

The function file is like this:

```
<?php 
function db_connect(){
    $link=mysqli_connect("host","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($link,"set names 'utf8'");
}

db_connect();

function func_1(){
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from ...");
    ...
}

function func_2(){
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from ...");
    ...
}

.
.
.

function func_100(){
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from ...");
    ...
}
?>
```

In the end I close the database connection. As I have checked max connection per user for my database is 50 and host provider will not change it (It's enough, they said).

So, generally how can I handle this problem ?  (simple PHP or OOP)

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong - I suspect the error is in some part of the code you're not showing us -, but your `db_connect` function is assigning a connection to a local variable, and then never passing it out. That's gonna burn you somewhere!

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I'm using " global $link " in the code where is needed. It's usually works fine but sometimes I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously opening more than one connection to your MySQL server in the process of handling each web page request.

Right after the definition of your `db_connect()` function in your code file, you call that function. That probably results in it being called more often than necessary. Each time you call it it consumes scarce resources from the connection pool.

Instead, do some work to make sure that function is called at most one time by the code processing each page. It's better to manage MySQL connections as part of your processing logic than to rely on `require_once` to do it for you. Make sure to close the open connections when you're done using them.

When you're sure you have at most one MySQL connection open per page being processed, then you may need to *reduce* the number of php documents your web server can handle simultaneously. That can be done by tuning the apache web server parameters `MaxClients` and / or `MaxRequestsPerChild`. The other popular web server, nginx, has similar parameters.   Reducing this capacity won't harm your users, because the web servers handle page requests from a queue.

Comment: They can use something like if (!$link) for avoid creating multiple connections, but, if they are really using only require_once, that's not the problem. But that's a nice point of better coding, i'm adding to my response.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of connections is too many for an invalid reason, then fix it. Take a look at when the connection is closed and how. Take a look at the persistency of the connection. If even making sure these are okay you have too many connections, then you might want to develop a multithreaded standalone application for your server in an environment which supports it and use maybe 10 threads of persistent connections there. This application would use a queue to know what needs to be asked from the database and where is the response to be sent back and whenever a worker thread finishes the process, get its result, send it to the requester and get on to the next item from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be blunt. There's not a coding solution here because of this

> As I have checked max connection per user for my database is 50 and host provider will not change it (It's enough, they said).

I suspect you're on some cheap/free hosting solution and they can keep it cheap/free because they throttle you. 50 is fine for, say, a personal Wordpress site with moderate traffic (say 1000 visits a day). But it's really easy to outstrip that. PHP is making more than 50 concurrent connections. That's a resource problem and you'll only solve it by increasing the number of connections available.

Since your current host won't do that, you need to move to one that can. Either that or accept that some of your visitors won't get the webpage they were expecting.

Comment: You're right, but it's not very cheap host (not for me!!). I just looking for best solution for the current situation.

Comment: FYI, you can have 10,000 connects and 9,999 disconnects within 5 minutes all happen within 50 db connections limit quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [singleton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) Either for just `$link` or all `function.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method `getLink` that you use in all query calls:

```
function getLink() {
    static $link;

    if(! $link) 
        $link = db_onnection() ;

    return $link;
}
```

And then in your queries:

```
mysqli_query(getLink(), "SELECT id,...");
```

Also, this is a variation of the singleton pattern which is a anti-pattern!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found when dealing with occasional high traffic. The key is to detect that the MySQL client has this error and wait to retry the connection.

It's not going to be as effective as reducing the number of connections required or increasing the connections, but in a pinch it should prevent the errors, assuming that connections are actually eventually being closed down. It will slow down the visitor experience (load times will suffer), but I expect it's better for users to wait a bit longer than get an error.

```
$sql = @new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$iSqlAttempt = 1;
//Detect the maximum connection error.
while ($sql->connect_errno == 1040 && $iSqlAttempt < 10) {
  //Sleep 10ms then retry. The time doubles after each attempt.
  usleep(pow(2, $iSqlAttempt)*10000);
  $sql = @new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
  $iSqlAttempt ++;
}
if ($sql->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error ('.$sql->connect_errno.') '.$sql->connect_error);
}
```

If the database still can't be reached after 10 attempts/10 seconds than it will fall back to reporting the error, but hopefully your situation is not as bad as that.

Hope it helps! Let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple options here:

First, you're using a $link variable out of scope. You can fix it with this code:

```
<?php 
$link = null;
function db_connect(){
    global $link;
    $link=mysqli_connect("host","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($link,"set names 'utf8'");
}

db_connect();

function func_1(){
    global $link;
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from ...");
    ...
}

function func_2(){
    global $link;
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from ...");
    ...
}

.
.
.

function func_100(){
    global $link;
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from ...");
    ...
}
?>
```

Second: (As suggested by O.Jones). You're only relying on require_once. You can check if the connection are stablished before creating it, with this:

```
if (!$link) db_connect();
```

(For that case, get the $link variable declared outside this file, on a always called one)

Third: PHP manages automatically the connection, and they are destroyed after last byte has served to the client. Maybe, if you close the connection by yourself with mysqli_close function when you doesn't need it anymore, you can get the problem solvented. You can check documentation about how to use this funcion here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

If the problem persist, maybe you need to use a persistent connection, for having less connections from your php to your database. You can achieve this prepending the host with "p:" (without quotes). For example, to connect to sql.myserver.com, you need to use:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("p:sql.myserver.com","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");
```

You can get more info about persistent connections with mysqli on php manual on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Comment: `global` is a [terrible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables/2496/global-variable-best-practices)

Comment: Why a -1? Maybe global is not the better option, but, at least are a solution without redoing all the code. If you have a better option, please publish it. I can learn with it. But with a despective and non-constructive critic, I can't learn anymore or solve this problem.

Comment: Because you're propagating a terrible way to code. What if someone uses `$link` somewhere else? Your code suddenly stops working. You've also suggested something else bad: persistent connections.  Speaking from experience, a persistent isn't released on termination, which is a bad thing for a website. You'll actually exacerbate the problem by doing that because PHP will still be creating **new** connections on top of the persistent ones.